# vb6 select whole word in string

Tags: regex, vb6, richtextbox

I am trying to search a string without regex perhaps a bad idea !

The search is acting on a string of text in a RichText Box
If I search for "is" the first word in the String is "This"
The last two letters of "This" is are highlighted in vbRed
The string to be searched has two other occurrences of "is" and these are found and highlighted as expected

**The question can I prevent the "is" in "This" from being found?**

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim pos As Integer
Dim strToFind As String
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Ask As String

pos = 1
strToFind = tbSearch.Text

Do
    strToFind = tbSearch.Text
    pos = InStr(1, strToSearch, strToFind)
    
    For Y = 1 To Len(strToSearch)
       
    Ask = MsgBox("Yes Next Occurrence or No To Exit ?", vbYesNo, "Question")
    
    If Ask = vbYes Then
    lbOne.AddItem pos
    tbAns.Text = pos

        If pos = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
    rtbOne.SelStart = pos - 1
    rtbOne.SelLength = Len(strToFind)
    rtbOne.SelColor = vbRed
    
    pos = InStr(pos + 1, strToSearch, strToFind)
        
    Else
    
    tbAns.Text = "NO"
    pos = InStr(pos + 1, strToSearch, strToFind)
    tbAns.Text = pos
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Next

    Loop Until pos > 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    strToSearch = "This is a lot of text that will be loaded in the lbText and we will search it is it a case sensative Search"
    
    rtbOne.Text = strToSearch
    tbSearch.Text = "is"

End Sub
```

If this is not possible a few suggestions on how to use regex
I know this much I need to add the Reference and this might be the
Pattern myRegExp.Pattern = "(.*)\strToFind\b(.*)"

Comment: With your current approach, you can look for the characters before and after the search string. Before the string should be a space and after the string can be any punctuation but not letters (ASCII codes 65-90, 97-122)

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I kind of understand but not sure how to implement  I did try something like this not much luck with this strToFind = " " & tbSearch.Text & " "

Comment: Rich Text Boxes have their own search function like MS Word. See `EM_FindTextExW` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findtextexw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was intrigued by the idea of a "built-in" search, as suggested by Bob77 and Mark, so I put together code to implement this idea.  The code uses a WinAPI call but is really pretty simple overall and supports moving forward and backward along with toggles for case sensitivity and whole words:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
Private Const WM_USER = &H400&
Private Const EM_GETOLEINTERFACE = (WM_USER + 60)

Private Enum Direction
   Forward = 1
   Backward = -1
End Enum

Private Doc As ITextDocument

Private Sub Form_Load()
   RichTextBox1.HideSelection = False
   RichTextBox1.Text = "is This is a lot of text that will be loaded in the lbText and we will " & _
                       "search it is it a case sensative Search" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                       "is and IS and is"
   
   SearchTerm.Text = "is"

   Dim Unknown As IUnknown
   SendMessage RichTextBox1.hwnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0&, Unknown
   Set Doc = Unknown
End Sub

Private Sub cmdForward_Click()
   Match SearchTerm.Text, chkWhole.Value, chkCase.Value, Forward
End Sub

Private Sub cmdBack_Click()
   Match SearchTerm.Text, chkWhole.Value, chkCase.Value, Backward
End Sub

Private Sub Match(ByVal SearchTerm As String, ByVal WholeWords As Integer, ByVal CaseSensitive As Integer, ByVal Direction As Direction)
   Dim Flags As Long
   Flags = 2 * WholeWords + 4 * CaseSensitive
   Doc.Selection.FindText SearchTerm, Direction * Doc.Selection.StoryLength, Flags
End Sub
```

You will need to add a reference to **RICHED20.dll** using the "Browse..." button in Project|References.

Comment: You have real command of VB 6 Do you do any VB.Net coding ? I am starting to give the VS 2019 a test drive seems everyone has moved to C# My VB 6 hard cover books are so out of date but still great ref esp Waite Group Interactive Course all 1127 pages at 0.045 cents/page ha

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  Yes, I do a lot of coding in VS2019 with both VB and C#.

Comment: I can not delete it Will Work On Fixing Thanks say HI to James_Duh he likes your work I just have a hard time with not being polite especially when you have the talent and knowledge

Answer (score 2):

TOM FindText accepts the tomMatchWord flag.  Just use that.  Don't screw aroung extracting text out of the control and then munching on it using slow scripting language crutches like RegEx.

Comment: Btw, OP might need more guidance like which reference to add for TOM, sample code how to use it with standard `RichTextBox` control and/or a little snippet with a call to `FindText` too.

Answer (score 1):

You might find following `InStrAll` implementation based on `VBScript.RegExp` useful.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Const STR_TEXT      As String = "This is a lot of text that will be loaded in the lbText and we will search it is it a case sensative Search"
    Dim vElem           As Variant
    
    For Each vElem In InStrAll(STR_TEXT, "is")
        Debug.Print vElem, Mid$(STR_TEXT, vElem, 2)
    Next
End Sub

Public Function InStrAll(sText As String, sSearch As String, Optional ByVal Compare As VbCompareMethod = vbTextCompare) As Variant
    Dim lIdx            As Long
    Dim vRetVal         As Variant
    
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = (Compare <> vbBinaryCompare)
        .Pattern = "[.*+?^${}()/|[\]\\]"
        .Pattern = "\b" & .Replace(sSearch, "\$&") & "\b"
        With .Execute(sText)
            If .Count = 0 Then
                vRetVal = Array()
            ElseIf .Count = 1 Then
                vRetVal = Array(.Item(0).FirstIndex + 1)
            Else
                ReDim vRetVal(0 To .Count - 1) As Variant
                For lIdx = 0 To .Count - 1
                    vRetVal(lIdx) = .Item(lIdx).FirstIndex + 1
                Next
            End If
        End With
    End With
    InStrAll = vRetVal
End Function
```

The point is first you have to escape the searched string (prefix all regex control symbols with backslash) and then wrap this escaped pattern with `\b`s before performing the "global" search for all matches.

The `InStrAll` function returns an array of indexes in the original text. It's up to your to impl actual color-coded highlighting in the RichTextBox control of your choice. (I would set the background color, not the foreground of the found snippet, if I had a choice. Notice how most browsers use yellow background for search results highlighting.)

Comment: Wonderful REGEX no to add the background YELLOW and incorporate the Dialog box I knew REGEX was the way to go but never used it in VB 6 Only use has been JavaFX and Android development Great Explanation by the way

Answer (score 1):

For a non-Regex approach, try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
   RichTextBox1.Text = "is This is a lot of text that will be loaded in the lbText and we will " & _
                       "search it is it a case sensative Search" & vbCr & vbCr & _
                       "is and is and is"
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim SearchTerm As String
   Dim SearchIndex As Integer
   
   SearchTerm = "is"
   SearchIndex = 1
   
   Do
      SearchIndex = InStr(SearchIndex, RichTextBox1.Text, SearchTerm)
      
      If isMatch(SearchIndex, SearchTerm) Then
         RichTextBox1.SelStart = SearchIndex - 1
         RichTextBox1.SelLength = Len(SearchTerm)
         RichTextBox1.SelColor = vbRed
      End If
      
      If SearchIndex > 0 Then SearchIndex = SearchIndex + Len(SearchTerm)
   Loop Until SearchIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Function isMatch(ByVal SearchIndex As Long, ByVal SearchTerm As String) As Boolean
   If SearchIndex = 1 Then
      If Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex + Len(SearchTerm), 1) = " " Then isMatch = True
   ElseIf SearchIndex + Len(SearchTerm) >= Len(RichTextBox1.Text) Then
      If Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex - 1, 1) = " " Then isMatch = True
   ElseIf SearchIndex > 1 Then
      If (Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex - 1, 1) = " " Or Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex - 1, 1) = vbCr) And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex + Len(SearchTerm), 1) = " " Then isMatch = True
   End If
End Function
```

As noted in the comments, the original code had limitations.  The code now supports matches at the beginning and end of the text, along with embedded breaks.  You will likely need to add more checks to the isMatch method.

Comment: `\b` (break) in regex terms is complicated to implement. OP might search for `123` or `!?#` then a following **letter** is a break not only whitespace. Also beginning/end of string is always a break but as currently implemented `Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, SearchIndex - 1, 1)` will always bomb out for SearchIndex = 1.

Comment: @wqw Yes, I agree.  I was alluding to the need of improving the inner If statement.  I just wanted to provide a simple example as a starting point.  I would likely lean towards regex, but the OP wanted a non-regex example.

Comment: @Vector I updated the code to be a little more robust.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Amazing code I will be reading for a while Not sure how the Function isMatch gets called Still trying to add the Dialog so I can INDEX through the RichTextBox string Two great answers to this question VB 6 was  or is so powerful